# Problem with adding sprite using CCSprite array in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have problem with following code.

```
        mySpriteArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

`star=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"22.png"];

    for(int i=0;i<10; i++) 
    {

        [mySpriteArray insertObject:star  atIndex:i];


    }


   // NSLog(@"x=%i",[mySpriteArray count]);



    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) // Opponents is NSMutableArray
    {
        CCSprite *tempSprite = (CCSprite *) [mySpriteArray objectAtIndex:i];


        tempSprite.position=ccp(100,100);


        [self addChild:tempSprite];


    }`

}
 
where star is a object of CCSprite and mySpriteArray is a mutable array.The problem is that when i run the program it crash and say

*** Assertion failure in -[GameScene addChild:z:tag:], /Users/salimsazzad/Desktop/balon hunter/libs/cocos2d/CCNode.m:305
2010-10-08 19:05:35.854 balon hunter[3967:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'child already added. It can't be added again'.

i can't understand whats wrong,i am adding 10 object,not 1 object in 10 times because  CCSprite *tempSprite = (CCSprite *) [mySpriteArray objectAtIndex:i];creating a new object each time.
so what is the problem???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created your star object once and added it 10 times to array:

```
star=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"22.png"];
for(int i=0;i<10; i++) 
{
    [mySpriteArray insertObject:star  atIndex:i];
}
```

So your array contains the same object and that's the reason of assertion you get.